# Big O of popping element until the list is empty

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

Assuming we have a list `ls` with `n` elements

`isEmpty()` returns true if `ls` is empty

```
def visit():
    count = 0
    while not isEmpty() do:
        print(ls.pop())
        count += 1
```

Would `visit()` take O(1) time because all operations are constant or would `visit()` take O(n) because it depends on the size of `ls`?

If `visit()`takes O(n), how do we adjust the code so that it takes O(1) time?

Comment: O(n). To make it O(1) do `count = len(ls); ls.clear()`. But as your code does nothing with `count` once the loop finishes, you could omit setting it.

Comment: `visit()` contains a while loop that depends on *n*, so it is not constant. If you perform a constant-time operation *n* times, then it takes *O(n)* time in total.

Comment: Why do you think you can remove n elements from a list in O(1) time? of cause you might be able to come up with a list-implementation which could do this, but as long as you can only remove one element at a time `.pop()`, you'll need n calls of `.pop()` to empty the list. => O(n)

Comment: @trincot I hate disagreeing with you, because I am likely to wind up being wrong.  But I have to disagree that this can be made `O(1)`.  See my answer for why I disagree.

Comment: That is because printing is making it obviously O(n). But I didn't regard that as essential. If it is, then of course it is a nobrainer that printing n things is O(n). This question should probably be tagged with `python` if that is an essential part of this algorithm question.

Answer (score 0):

This code is probably `O(n)`.  Read to the bottom to see why it CAN be (but usually isn't) worse than that.  Also, contrary to the comments, there is no way to make it `O(1)`.  There are two reasons for that.

The first is that your code as it stands is printing `n` things.  Creating `O(n)` output takes `O(n)` time.

The second is an internal one.  You can indeed call `ls.clear()`.  But reading [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c) you'll find that under the hood that calls the following function:

```
static int
_list_clear(PyListObject *a)
{
    Py_ssize_t i;
    PyObject **item = a->ob_item;
    if (item != NULL) {
        /* Because XDECREF can recursively invoke operations on
           this list, we make it empty first. */
        i = Py_SIZE(a);
        Py_SET_SIZE(a, 0);
        a->ob_item = NULL;
        a->allocated = 0;
        while (--i >= 0) {
            Py_XDECREF(item[i]);
        }
        PyMem_Free(item);
    }
    /* Never fails; the return value can be ignored.
       Note that there is no guarantee that the list is actually empty
       at this point, because XDECREF may have populated it again! */
    return 0;
}
```

Note that, for garbage collection purposes, there is a loop calling `Py_XDECREF` for each item of the array.  That operation is usually `O(n)`, but with very good constants.

I say "usually" because when we decrement reference counts, we may garbage collect.  Garbage collecting a complex object takes time proportional to its complexity.  So, for example, if your array contained `n` complex objects of size `O(n)`, this would take time `O(n^2)`.

That said in languages like Java and JavaScript that don't rely on reference counting, without the `print` this really would be `O(1)`.  But that's an accounting trick from moving garbage collection into a different operation.  The need to free memory is a necessary tax on our software, and we'll wind up paying it somehow.

Comment: I agree that the need to decrement each reference count is a real part of the complexity. I think, though, that triggering garbage collection is more like an "interrupt" that suspends the operation for an arbitrary and independent amount of time, and so it would't be fair to "blame" the `clear` operation for that.

Comment: Wouldn't a good implementation do this asynchronously? Is CPython the only parser for Python?

Comment: Whether or not it is asynchronous, I could put this more simply: the time it takes to do garbage collection is *not* a function of `n`. As such, the *complexity* would be O(1), but that could be hiding a very big or very small constant, depending on the state of your program, which is not something in the control of the `list` type.

Comment: @trincot All of PyPy, Jython and IronPython use real garbage collection. None are fully compatible with Python. "Good implementation" is a somewhat nebulous here - there are tradeoffs and reference counting has some real advantages when holding on to expensive external resources like network connections.

Comment: @chepner Even if you discount the time taken for actual garbage collection, updating each reference count is directly part of the implementation, and so I would say it is part of the `clear` operation.  As for overall performance, there is a theorem that for some programs reference counting is faster, and for others garbage collection is. True GC cleans up circular references. Reference counting gives clear resource cleanup semantics. Neither is unambiguously better than the other.

Comment: Yes, I agreed that decrementing each reference counted towords `clear` being O(n).

Answer (score 0):

The `visit` function that you provided takes O(n) time as it is written, since it must do a `pop` for every item in `ls`.

However, I am guessing that you cut this function out of a larger algorithm, and in that larger algorithm it's very likely that this `visit` function takes amortized O(1) time, because the *total time taken by all calls* to `visit()` is proportional to the total number of elements added to `ls`.